# user profile routes configuration in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a simple problem but I just can't figure it out. I wrote a method that reads parameters from the url  (one parameter which is the username) and queries all data to that user and displays it in the page.

the only problem is that the method is part of a controller and naturally it has to show in the url (which is simply said: not too nice for sharing. Also I have to write the string as follows:

```
www.domain.com/controller/profile_guest?user=username
```

I want to get rid of all that is before username. So for it to show as:

```
www.domain.com/username
```

Now there are two scenarios to cover here.

a) someone browse the catalogue, clicks on profile name and then redirects to profile page. once there he likes what he sees, he copies url, and share it.

b) someone receives the shared link and clicks on it, so what should load is the profile page with the url he received not the full one showing controller and method.

is this possible to achieve?

Thanks for the help :)

Update:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main/index";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Comment: Yes with routes it is possible. Read this section in the manual http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: Use the `404_override` functionality. Simply put, if anyone goes to an URL not already routed/mapped within CodeIgniter, it will call what ever controller/action you place in the `404_override`. From here, you can simply read what username they were trying to read and show the appropriate page.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this route:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "controller/profile_guest/$1";
```

but any other route, you will need to write it manually above this route.
for example:

```
$route['controller/view'] = "controller/view";
$route['(:any)'] = "controller/profile_guest/$1";
```

**Explain:**

The routes are handled in the order in which they appear on your routes.php file, so if you put `$route['(:any)']` at the top, it will handle anything.

suppose that you have a contoller and a function inside it, and you need to execute it for example: `www.domain.com/contoller/function`, you cann't execute your function because it will match this route `$route['(:any)']`, so you need to define a route for it before `$route['(:any)']` 
for example:

```
$route['contoller/function'] = "controller/function"
$route['(:any)'] = "controller/profile_guest/$1";
```

and do the same thing with all your contollers and its function, but you have to put `$route['(:any)']` at the last route.

Comment: I have only one more route on routes.php and it is updated above in question. could you please clarify what you means?

Comment: Note that in CI 3.0+, `:any` will *not* match slashes, so it will only apply to one URI segment.